# GLM Repeated Measures in SPSS: how to use factor's actual values instead of 1-n labels?

Tags: spss, glm

In my analysis, I have nominal factors with values. For example, a factor called `Width` has 4 levels with these values: 2, 4, 10, and 20.

When I want to do Repeated Measures, SPSS asks me to define each factor with its respective number of levels (with no option to set the values). This is understandable, but when I get to choosing Within Subject Variables, I only see 1-n labels for every factor:

[image]

This is not a problem in itself, but it is always these generic 1-n in any analysis output SPSS gives me! For example, the plot axis for `Width` looks like this:

[image]

Same with labels in all the tables. I can't seem to find any way of setting these labels other than painstakingly renaming them one by one on the plots, tables, etc.

**Is there any way to tell SPSS to use the actual values for labels?**

Comment: In general in SPSS you should try pasting the syntax to a syntax window - this will help to understand the analysis parameters and let you tweak them before running. It will also enable you to share the code in your post if you're still stuck.

Comment: @eli-k good point, thanks. I checked the [GLM command](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spss-statistics/29.0.0?topic=reference-glm-repeated-measures) and couldn't find any reference (or subcommand) for using values. I guess that means it is not possible?